# How to access a .txt file at a secured url?

Tags: python

I want to read a file from a secured url.

For example: https://foo.net/test.txt

when I use:

```
readtext = urllib.urlopen('https://foo.net/test.txt').read()
```

I get a request for username and password. After entering them I can read the file. Is there a way to hardcode the username and password ?

Comment: By hardcode you mean...

Comment: You mean by Hardcode an encryption or ?

Comment: I tried using urllib2.urlopen(url), this gave me Error 401Authentication Required

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper 
to specify username='user'

Comment: Yes. There is. You can do http basic auth pretty trivially.

Comment: Is it necessary to do with urlopen2?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's almost as trivial to do in urllib as it is in requests, but requests is just so darn pretty:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r = requests.get('https://foo.net/test.txt', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```